# Use MVC Router to determine if route exists

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to use the ASP.NET Core MVC Router to determine, if a redirect to a specific location might be successfull?

I'd like to inject the MVC Router and just ask it, if the route I want to use exists at all, but I'm struggling finding the correct classes to inject and did not see any method of use in the MVCRouter.

I would also be okay in overriding the default router and extend it with the neccessary methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to inject `IActionSelector` to your component.

That component is responsible for controller action selection, and can tell you if there is a route with given parameters (and even if there is an ambiguous match).

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IActionSelector _actionSelector;

    public HomeController(IActionSelector actionSelector)
    {
        _actionSelector = actionSelector;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["action"] = "DoesNotExist";
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
        var routeContext = new RouteContext(HttpContext)
        {
            RouteData = routeData
        };
        IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> candidates = _actionSelector.SelectCandidates(routeContext);
        if (candidates == null || candidates.Count == 0)
        {
            //No actions matched
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var actionDescriptor = _actionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(routeContext, candidates);
                if(actionDescriptor == null)
                {
                    //No action matched
                }
                //Action matched
            }
            catch (AmbiguousActionException)
            {
                //More than 1 action matched
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

It's essentially what `MvcRouteHandler` does. First finds all the possible candidates, then filters that to the best candidate. It can throw an exception if it finds more than one, which you may or may not want to handle.

I thought if you could somehow do this easier by extending a component to change behaviour, but `MvcRouteHandler` is not that easy to extend. It currently just logs a message if no action matches, which does not affect the return value. And we can't really change the signature there.

Comment: That's really close to what I was looking for.  
Essentially I want to look, if a derived location exists, if there was a 404. So I have to use a Middleware and I have currently no Idea how to constuct the RouteContext from an arbitrary Url.
Nevertheless I appreciate your effort to help me.

Comment: Luckily that is actually an ASP.NET Core specific thing, not MVC. You'll have to get the route collection and attempt to resolve it from there I think. I can take a look at it later.

Comment: As I understand it, MVC will build an `IRouter`, the latter implements RouteAsync() and this will fill `RouteData` in the `RouteContext`-Object. But creating the `IRouter` seems expensive. Regarding that I probably should not try to detect, if the route exists (or at least only for academic purpose) ...

Comment: MVC's handlers don't populate `RouteData`, it's done before it gets hit by `RouteBase`, which calls `TemplateMatcher` to do the matching. You can actually access the populated `RouteData` in middleware or anywhere by accessing the `IRoutingFeature` through HttpContext. You would have to do this after the `RouterMiddleware` is run, which would be quite tricky, as that is literally the thing that calls the MVC handler to call your action.

Comment: The main problem with your question is that the routing system is not really designed so that you could ask it if some particular URL would bring you a 200 OK or a 404. The routers just call what they are supposed to and that's that. And essentially what you would end up doing in the full solution would be pretty much what ASP.NET Core/MVC Core *already do*. Another tricky thing is that there are two things that make a match. 1. URL must match a route template, 2. the parsed route values must match an action. You'd need to do at least 2 different things with different components.

Comment: Though if you actually do want to do this, there is a code sample here: https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/350

Comment: Well appearantly I should not do that as of now.. nervertheless I learned something about ASP.NET Core Routing, which is nice :)