# See which controller and action will be executed from a route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

In ASP .NET Core, how can I given a route (for instance `/api/users/28`) see which controller will be used, and which action will be used? In this case for instance, it would be `UsersController` and its `Get(int id)` action.

I would love if there was a way to access some kind of router that could tell me this, so that I don't have to replicate the internal routing system myself. I just haven't been able to find this using the official documentation on ASP .NET Core routing.

**Edit 1** My question is not a duplicate. I'm not looking for options on determining if a route exists - I want to know what exact action and controller will handle it.

**Edit 2** Here's what my current code looks like, and what I've tried:

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Path = "/api/users/28";
httpContext.Request.Method = "GET";

var context = new RouteContext(httpContext);

//throws an exception: AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched.
var bestCandidate = _actionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(context,
    _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use MVC Router to determine if route exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074711/use-mvc-router-to-determine-if-route-exists)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I clarified why.

Comment: You defenetly need to add `httpContext.Request.Method = "<GET/POST/PUT/DELETE>";`.  Regarding `candidates`: it is 0 as `SelectCandidates` method uses `context.RouteData.Routers` internally to get available routes => this is empty list in such case.

Comment: Interesting. I updated my sample - it's still not working. And now when doing `SelectBestCandidate`, I get the error `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched` between controllers `UserController` and `GroupController`. The two have `HttpGet` attributes with very different routes (`api/users/{userId}` and `api/groups`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `IActionSelector` only matches the HTTP methods etc. and completely ignores the route templates.

Thanks to [Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833802/set) answer and https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/, I came up with the following solution:

```
public ManualActionSelector(IActionSelector actionSelector, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
{
    _actionSelector = actionSelector;
    _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
}

public ActionDescriptor GetMatchingAction(string path, string httpMethod)
{
    var actionDescriptors = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items;

    // match by route template
    var matchingDescriptors = new List<ActionDescriptor>();
    foreach (var actionDescriptor in actionDescriptors)
    {
        var matchesRouteTemplate = MatchesTemplate(actionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template, path);
        if (matchesRouteTemplate)
        {
            matchingDescriptors.Add(actionDescriptor);
        }
    }

    // match action by using the IActionSelector
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Path = path;
    httpContext.Request.Method = httpMethod;
    var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);
    return _actionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(routeContext, matchingDescriptors.AsReadOnly());
}


public bool MatchesTemplate(string routeTemplate, string requestPath)
{
    var template = TemplateParser.Parse(routeTemplate);

    var matcher = new TemplateMatcher(template, GetDefaults(template));
    var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
    return matcher.TryMatch(requestPath, values);
}

// This method extracts the default argument values from the template. From https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/
private RouteValueDictionary GetDefaults(RouteTemplate parsedTemplate)
{
    var result = new RouteValueDictionary();

    foreach (var parameter in parsedTemplate.Parameters)
    {
        if (parameter.DefaultValue != null)
        {
            result.Add(parameter.Name, parameter.DefaultValue);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It first tries to match all routes by the templates. The it calls the `IActionSelector`, which does the rest. You can use it like this:

```
var action = GetMatchingAction("/api/users/28", "GET"); // will return null if no matching route found
```

Comment: This is great - is there a way where I can (given a controller instance) only look at routes that belong to that specific controller?

Comment: I believe that the `GetDefaults` method can be simplified to this one line `return new RouteValueDictionary(parsedTemplate.ToRoutePattern().Defaults);` (available since .net 2.2).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `HttpContext` instance, you may do

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

//HttpContext httpContext;
//IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider
//IActionSelector selector

var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);
var x = selector.SelectBestCandidate(routeContext, provider.ActionDescriptors.Items);
var route =  new 
{
    Action = x.RouteValues["Action"],
    Controller = x.RouteValues["Controller"],
    Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name,
    Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template,
    Constrains = x.ActionConstraints,
};
```

---

---

You can find all of the actions by using the `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` service ([default MVC implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.cs)) and analyze `Template` string:

```
//IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider
var routes = provider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Select(x => new { 
           Action = x.RouteValues["Action"], 
           Controller = x.RouteValues["Controller"], 
           Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name, 
           Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template,
           Constrains = x.ActionConstraints
        }).ToList();
```

To get HTTP methods look into `Constrains` - this is a list of `IActionConstraintMetadata` items. Among them, there will be `HttpMethodActionConstrains` item that contains the HTTP method(s) for action.

Example of result:

```
[{"action":"GetValues","controller":"Values","name":null,"template":"api/Values","constrains":[{"httpMethods":["GET"],"order":100}]},
{"action":"GetValuesById","controller":"Values","name":null,"template":"api/Values/{id}","constrains":[{"httpMethods":["GET"],"order":100}]},
{"action":"PostValue","controller":"Values","name":null,"template":"api/Values","constrains":[{"httpMethods":["POST"],"order":100}]},
{"action":"PutValue","controller":"Values","name":null,"template":"api/Values/{id}","constrains":[{"httpMethods":["PUT"],"order":100}]},
{"action":"DeleteValue","controller":"Values","name":null,"template":"api/Values/{id}","constrains":[{"httpMethods":["DELETE"],"order":100}]}]
```

Comment: Can you clarify more on the action constraints part?

Comment: Great - that helps a bit. But how can I take the original string (`/api/v2/users/28`) and map it over to the relevant action and controller? That's what the original question is about.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenze updated for the case when you have HttpContext. In general,  I am afraid you cannot do this properly having only URL string, as Routing using much more information from incoming Request: HTTP method, query params / body msg, headers...

Comment: Almost there! Unfortunately, the URL I get is just a string - it is not necessarily from the current HTTP context. I tried constructing a `DefaultHttpContext` and using that, but without luck. To clarify, with a `DefaultHttpContext` where I set `Request.Path` on it, `SelectBestCandidate` returns my `HomeController` no matter what, and `SelectCandidates` returns 0 results.

Comment: I have edited my question to demonstrate what my current code looks like.

Comment: I am getting this error with 7 matched actions:
Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Any ideas? I just want the one matched action.